# I can I merge multiple rows into one in Excel after I sorted the data?

Tags: excel, geojson

I have a really big GEOJSON file. I read it in EditPad Lite and selected the data I needed and saved it in .CSV. I opened the .CSV in Excel and used the "Text to columns" tool to sort a particular set of data in the list. Once it is sorted, I'd need to save it back again in a way EditPad Lite would be able to read it. I'd need to concatenate, or merge, all those trillions of columns into just one separated by commas. How can I do this? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Why not just **Save** it as a `.csv` file? And, if your data has entries that might be misinterpreted by Excel as dates, or if the date format in your computer differs from the date format being used in any of your columns, you would be better served by **importing** the csv file rather than **opening** it. Then you'll have control over how Excel interprets the data.  By the way, I assume `trillions of columns` was hyperbole.  Excel can only handle 16,384 columns.  If you have more than that, you'll need a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy - you can do it using `CONCAT` and a little ingenuity.

If your data is in column A, put a single comma in every cell adjacent to it in column B (except for the last row), as shown in the mock up below:

```
      A     B
1    a     ,
2    b     ,
3    c     ,
4    d     ,
5    e
```

Then simple do `=CONCAT(A1:B5)` and the result will yield a single string `a,b,c,d,e`

**EDIT:**
If your data is in columns, you can still do this - you just have to transpose and use an array formula. See below:

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F
1    a     b     c     d     e     f
2    ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     
3
```

Then just do `{=CONCAT(TRANSPOSE(A1:F2))}`. Note that this is an array formula - you need to press `Ctrl` `Shift` `Enter` to calculate as an array (`Cmd` `Shift` `Enter` on a Mac). It should yield the desired result `a,b,c,d,e,f`.

Note that array formulas consume a large amount of memory. If you have an excessive amount of data, Excel may not be the best tool for this. Also, if there are more columns in your dataset than Excel can handle, this isn't going to work. You may consider trying to just save as CSV, or using a VBA script.